# Optimizing my postgres query

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

Can I optimize this query, or modify the table structure in order to shorten the execution time? I don't really understand the output of `EXPLAIN`. Am I missing some index?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, 
             q.query_str
      FROM click_fact cf, 
           query q,
           date_dim dd,
           queries_p_day_mv qpd
        WHERE dd.date_dim_id = qpd.date_dim_id 
        AND qpd.query_id = q.query_id
        AND type = 'S' 
        AND cf.query_id = q.query_id *emphasized text*
        AND  dd.pg_date BETWEEN '2010-12-29' AND '2011-01-28' 
        AND qpd.interface_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT interface_id from interface WHERE lang = 'sv')
      GROUP BY q.query_str          
      ORDER BY count DESC;
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=19170.15..19188.80 rows=7460 width=12)
   Sort Key: (count(*))
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=18597.03..18690.28 rows=7460 width=12)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10.20..18559.73 rows=7460 width=12)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10.20..14975.36 rows=2452 width=20)
                     Join Filter: (qpd.interface_id = interface.interface_id)
                     ->  Unique  (cost=1.03..1.04 rows=1 width=4)
                           ->  Sort  (cost=1.03..1.04 rows=1 width=4)
                                 Sort Key: interface.interface_id
                                 ->  Seq Scan on interface  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=1 width=4)
                                       Filter: (lang = 'sv'::text)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9.16..14943.65 rows=2452 width=24)
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=9.16..14133.58 rows=2452 width=8)
                                 Hash Cond: (qpd.date_dim_id = dd.date_dim_id)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on queries_p_day_mv qpd  (cost=0.00..11471.93 rows=700793 width=12)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=8.81..8.81 rows=28 width=4)
                                       ->  Index Scan using date_dim_pg_date_index on date_dim dd  (cost=0.00..8.81 rows=28 width=4)
                                             Index Cond: ((pg_date >= '2010-12-29'::date) AND (pg_date <= '2011-01-28'::date))
                           ->  Index Scan using query_pkey on query q  (cost=0.00..0.32 rows=1 width=16)
                                 Index Cond: (q.query_id = qpd.query_id)
               ->  Index Scan using click_fact_query_id_index on click_fact cf  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=36 width=4)
                     Index Cond: (cf.query_id = qpd.query_id)
                     Filter: (cf.type = 'S'::bpchar)
```

**Updated with EXPLAIN ANALYZE:**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, 
             q.query_str
      FROM click_fact cf, 
           query q,
           date_dim dd,
           queries_p_day_mv qpd
        WHERE dd.date_dim_id = qpd.date_dim_id 
        AND qpd.query_id = q.query_id
        AND type = 'S' 
        AND cf.query_id = q.query_id 
        AND  dd.pg_date BETWEEN '2010-12-29' AND '2011-01-28' 
        AND qpd.interface_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT interface_id from interface WHERE lang = 'sv')
      GROUP BY q.query_str
      ORDER BY count DESC;
                                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=19201.06..19220.52 rows=7784 width=12) (actual time=51017.162..51046.102 rows=17586 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(*))
   Sort Method:  external merge  Disk: 632kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=18600.67..18697.97 rows=7784 width=12) (actual time=50935.411..50968.678 rows=17586 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10.20..18561.75 rows=7784 width=12) (actual time=42.079..43666.404 rows=3868592 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10.20..14975.91 rows=2453 width=20) (actual time=23.678..14609.282 rows=700803 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: (qpd.interface_id = interface.interface_id)
                     ->  Unique  (cost=1.03..1.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.104..0.110 rows=1 loops=1)
                           ->  Sort  (cost=1.03..1.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.100..0.102 rows=1 loops=1)
                                 Sort Key: interface.interface_id
                                 Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on interface  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.038..0.041 rows=1 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (lang = 'sv'::text)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9.16..14944.20 rows=2453 width=24) (actual time=23.550..12553.786 rows=700808 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=9.16..14133.80 rows=2453 width=8) (actual time=18.283..3885.700 rows=700808 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (qpd.date_dim_id = dd.date_dim_id)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on queries_p_day_mv qpd  (cost=0.00..11472.08 rows=700808 width=12) (actual time=0.014..1587.106 rows=700808 loops=1)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=8.81..8.81 rows=28 width=4) (actual time=18.221..18.221 rows=31 loops=1)
                                       ->  Index Scan using date_dim_pg_date_index on date_dim dd  (cost=0.00..8.81 rows=28 width=4) (actual time=14.388..18.152 rows=31 loops=1)
                                             Index Cond: ((pg_date >= '2010-12-29'::date) AND (pg_date <= '2011-01-28'::date))
                           ->  Index Scan using query_pkey on query q  (cost=0.00..0.32 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=700808)
                                 Index Cond: (q.query_id = qpd.query_id)
               ->  Index Scan using click_fact_query_id_index on click_fact cf  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=36 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.022 rows=6 loops=700803)
                     Index Cond: (cf.query_id = qpd.query_id)
                     Filter: (cf.type = 'S'::bpchar)
```

Comment: I suggest using JOIN syntax instead of the sql92 style, and then see if you get the same plan. I know it shouldn't happen, but I've seen big changes in speed between the two styles at times - perhaps because being clearer in your intention helps the query optimizer too?

Comment: @iain: could you please post a sample query which changes its plan in `PostgreSQL` when rewritten `ANSI` style?

Comment: @Quassinoi - no, because I don't and won't have access to any of the queries that I've seen it happen with. I've seen it most on mysql to be fair. You'll just have to live with the anecdote :)

Comment: If you post EXPLAIN ANALYZE and not just EXPLAIN output, it becomes much easier to find out where your actual problem is.

Comment: @magnus Thanks! Updated with EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to eliminate subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, 
         q.query_str
  FROM click_fact cf, 
       query q,
       date_dim dd,
       queries_p_day_mv qpd
    WHERE dd.date_dim_id = qpd.date_dim_id 
    AND qpd.query_id = q.query_id
    AND type = 'S' 
    AND cf.query_id = q.query_id 
    AND  dd.pg_date BETWEEN '2010-12-29' AND '2011-01-28' 
    AND qpd.interface_id = interface.interface_id
    AND interface.lang = 'sv'
  GROUP BY q.query_str          
  ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Also, if interface table is big, creating ingex on lang may help. index in            queries_p_day_mv on day_dim_id may help too.

Generally, the first thing to try is to look for Seq Scans and try to make them index scans by creating indexes.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count, 
        q.query_str
FROM    date_dim dd
JOIN    queries_p_date_mv qpd
ON      qpd.date_dim_id = dd.date_dim_id
        AND qpd.interface_id IN
        (
        SELECT  interface_id
        FROM    interface
        WHERE   lang = 'sv'
        )
JOIN    query q
ON      q.query_id = qpd.query_id
JOIN    click_fact cf
ON      cf.query_id = q.query_id 
        AND cf.type = 'S' 
WHERE   dd.pg_date BETWEEN '2010-12-29' AND '2011-01-28' 
GROUP BY
        q.query_str          
ORDER BY
        count DESC
```

Create the following indexes (in addition to your existing ones):

```
queries_p_date_mv (interface_id, date_dim_id)
interface (lang)
click_fact (query_id, type)
```

Could you please post the definitions of your tables?

Comment: Is there any chance you could explain the reasoning behind some of the optimizations you made?  Thanks in advance.